# Проблемы с jTable и DefaultTableModel

Tags: jtable, java

Пишу курсовую и возникла проблема. Имеются 2 jFrame. В одной происходит заполнение таблицы (jTable) из БД. Вторая необходима для ввода данных и добавления их в БД и таблицу. Т.к. обратиться к методу setModel из второй формы я не могу приходится всячески извращаться. Теперь вопрос: можно ли отслеживать изменения в DefaultTableModel и, если они произошли, обновлять данные в таблице? Не хочется изобретать велосипеды.

---

Frame1 обращается к БД и выводит данные на jTable1. Также на Frame1 есть кнопка jButton1. Во время нажатия на кнопку должна открываться Frame2, на которой расположено несколько(не суть важно) элементов textField, которые используются для заполнения полей записи. Плюс на Frame2 есть кнопка jButton2, которая необходима для добавления записи в БД и обновления данных в jTable1. Вопрос: как это осуществить?

**Код:**

Класс Frame1, его конструктор и обработчик нажатия кнопки jButton1. В конструкторе я подключаюсь к MySQL, создаю БД с именем goods и заполняю jTable.

```
public class Frame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

                    Connection conn = null;
                    Statement stmt = null;
                    ResultSet rs = null;
                    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
                    String login = "root";
                    String password = "";

                    DefaultTableModel data = new DefaultTableModel();
                    Vector idV = new Vector();
                    Vector nameV = new Vector();
                    Vector priceV = new Vector();

    public Frame1() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
                    initComponents();
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, login, password);
                    System.out.println("connect ok " + conn.toString());
                    stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

                    if (stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS goods") == 1) {
                        stmt.executeQuery("USE goods");
                      stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS names (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                                + "name TEXT, price INT)");
                    }

                    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM names");

                    while(rs.next()) {
                        idV.add(rs.getString("id"));
                        nameV.add(rs.getString("name"));
                        priceV.add(rs.getString("price"));
                    }

                    data.addColumn("id", idV);
                    data.addColumn("name", nameV);
                    data.addColumn("price", priceV);

                    jTable1.setModel(data);
    }

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        new Frame2().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Обработчик нажатия кнопки jButton2:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    name = jTextField1.getText();
                    price = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());

            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO names VALUES (NULL, '" + name + "', '" + price + "')");
    }
```

Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию jButton2 новая запись добавлялась в jTable1?

Comment: можно ;) нечего не понятно, давай куски кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему бы в обработчик события нажатия кнопки JButton2 не передать table1? можно сделать по другому, описать метод который будет возвращать таблицу и вы уже в нужном месте будете получать доступ к ней.

```
class PressButton2 ActionListiner impliment {
Jtable table;

PresButton2(Jtable table) {
   this.table = table;
}
```

Это такойже слушатель событий

```
JButton aa =new JButton("test");
aa.addActionListiner(new PressButton2());
```

PressButton2 создаешь в своем классе где работаешь
piblic MainClass {

```
public class Frame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
....
JButton aa =new JButton("test");
aa.addActionListiner(new PressButton2());
.....
}

class PressButton2 ActionListiner impliment {
....
}
}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       table.---Ваши действия;
    }

    }
```

Comment: То есть мне нужно будет создать еще один класс?

Comment: а мы в обработчик события jButton2 будем передавать ссылку на table1? Т.е. при любом изменении объекта table изменится и сама table1?